# Decorator Functions in Python

Tags: python

The Decorator Function of Python has this simple template

```
@A

@B

def C():
```

It modify the C function to C=A(B(C));

Let's give a more specific example

```
@request("POST", "%(channel)d/sequence/%(args)s") 
@response("%d")

    def outputSequence(self, channel, args):
        self.checkDigitalChannelExported(channel)
        self.checkPostingValueAllowed()
        self.checkDigitalChannel(channel)
        (period, sequence) = args.split(",")
        period = int(period)
        GPIO.outputSequence(channel, period, sequence)
        return int(sequence[-1])
```

So from the above, would the transformed function be

like request(response(outSequence(self, channel, args))?

Comment: Do you mean function *decorators*?  To my knowledge there is no such thing as a *decorative* function in python.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking. As per my question. Are you trying to make sense of decorators that take arguments?

Answer (score 5):

Parameterized decorators behave a bit differently. The function `request` accepts only the arguments, it's a *decorator maker*:

```
def request(arg1, arg2):
    def my_decorator(func):
        def wrapper():
           #do something
        return wrapper
    return my_decorator
```

So the function calls is like:

```
decorator = request(arg1, arg2)
response_decorator = decorator(response(arg1, arg2))
outputSequence = response_decorator(outputSequence(self, arg1, arg2))
```

Here's a  tiny example:

```
>>> def make_decorators(arg1, arg2):
        def decorator(func):
            def wrapper():
                print("We got here!")
            return wrapper
        return decorator

>>> @make_decorators(1, 2)
    def my_func():
        pass


>>> my_func()
We got here!
```

Answer (score 2):

Close. When a decorator is given one or more arguments, the effect is to call the decorator, which returns a function that is then applied to the function it is decorating. The effect is something more like (as Niklas B. pointed out):

```
request("POST", "%(channel)d/sequence/%(args)s")(
   response("%d")(
       outputSequence))(self, channel, args)
```

Comment: Actually calling the function would be more like `request("POST", "%(channel)d/sequence/%(args)s")(response("%d")(outputSequence))(self, channel, args)`. However, what the decorator does is `outputSequence = request(...)(response(...)(outputSequence))`